# Mean and variance of a probability generating function(Bert Fristedt).

Tags: probability-theory, variance, means, moment-generating-functions

For  $p \in[0,1]$. Prove that the function 
 $$\rho(s)=\begin{cases} 
      1-\sqrt{1-4p(1-p)s^{2}} & 0\leq s< 1 \\
      1 & s=1
   \end{cases}$$
is a probability generating function of a distribution.

Calculate the mean and the variance.

**Attempt of solution:**
It is necessary to verify that the conditions of this Theorem are satisfied:
[image]

Suppose $F$ is the distribution function related to $\rho$.

I already proved that the function is a probability generating function of a distribution.
$$ \begin{align*} F(\{\infty\})=1-\rho(1-)=&1-\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{-}}1-\sqrt{1-4p(1-p)s^{2}}\\
&=1-(1-\sqrt{1-4p(1-p))}\\
&=\sqrt{1-4p(1-p))}
\end{align*} $$
rewriting 
$$ \begin{align*}
F(\{\infty\})&=\sqrt{1-4p(1-p))}\\
            &=\frac{|2p-1|^{2}}{\sqrt{|(2p-1)|^{2}}}\\
            &=|2p-1| \end{align*}$$

Now we have $F(\{k\})=\frac{\rho^{k}(0)}{k!}$. So for 
$0<k=2m<\infty$ with $m\in\mathbb{N }$

$$ F(\{k\})=\frac{\rho^{k}(0)}{k!}=4^{m}{\frac{m}{k}\choose{m}}[p(1-p)]^{m} $$
for $k$ odd y $k=0$, $F(\{k\})=0$.

I'm trying to calculate the mean as follows:

$$
\rho^{\prime}(1-)=\lim _{s \nearrow 1} \frac{1-\rho(s)}{1-s}=\lim_{s\nearrow 1}\frac{\sqrt{1-4p(1-p)s^{2}}}{1-s}
$$

I want to know if I'm on the right track.
The answer of the book is: The mean is infinite and thus the variance is  undefined. How can I prove this?

Comment: It seems something is missing in your question. It just says "Prove that the function" without any indication of what is to be proved.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this is the missing part: "is a probability generating function of a distribution". But I already proved that.

Comment: How did you prove that the function is a probability generating function? That would give more context to this question to see what type of approach you have taken.

Comment: Well, strangely enough Mathematica said that your limit in question for the mean is "Indeterminate" as opposed to $+\infty$.

Comment: That is what I have so far

Comment: Oh, well if you have $F(\{\infty\})>0$, shouldn't it automatically follow that the mean is infinite?